# Brownian motion and Stochastic Integration

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I have two questions relating stochastic integration which perhaps could be answered together.

---

**First question**:

First of all, I don't really understand why we can't use Riemann-Stieltjes integration when a Brownian motion is the integrator (has something to do with its infinite variation but I don't see how that affects the integral).

**Second Question**:

For the second question (I think the more general case), we first need to define the following spaces

$$
\begin{align}
M_{0, loc}^{c} &:= \text{Space of all continuous local martingales } (M_{t})_{t \in [0, T]} \text{ with }  M_{0} = 0 \\
FV_{0}^{c} &:= \text{Space of all adapted stochastic processes } (A_{t})_{t \in [0, T]} \text{ with } A_{0} = 0 \\& \hspace{0.6cm} \text{ and continuous sample paths of finite variation}
\end{align}
$$

Now, I have the following lemma:

*Every continuous local martingale* $(M_{t})_{t \in [0, T]}$ *with sample paths of finite variation is constant. In particular, one has* $M_{0, loc}^{c} \cap FV_{0}^{c} = \{0 \}.$

This lemma allegedly is responsible, that we cannot construct the integrals with respect to martingales based on classical Riemann-Stieltjes integration. I don't really see why this is the case either.

---

I hope you understand my questions and are able to answer them.

Best regards,

Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a standard Brownian motion $(B_t)$ and let's try to compute $\int_0^t B_s\mathrm{d}B_s$ in the Riemann-Stieltjes sense.

Let $0=t_0<t_1<...<t_n=t$ be a partition and let $y_i=t_{i-1}$ or $y=t_i$ for $i=1,...,n$ be two intermediate partitions. Thus,
\begin{align*}
S^1_n(t) &= \sum_{i=1}^n B_{t_{i-1}}(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}}), \\
S^2_n(t) &= \sum_{i=1}^n B_{t_{i}}(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}}),
\end{align*}
are Riemann-Stieltjes sums.

If the Riemann-Stieltjes integral exists, $S_n^1(t)-S_n^2(t)\to0$ as $\max\limits_{i=1,...,n}\{t_i-t_{i-1}\}\to0$. However,
\begin{align*}
S^2_n(t)- S^1_n(t)&= \sum_{i=1}^n (B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}})^2 >0
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[S^2_n(t)- S^1_n(t)]&= \sum_{i=1}^n (t_i-t_{i-1})=t \neq 0.
\end{align*}
Thus, the Riemann-Stieltjes integral does not exist for a Brownian motion as integrator.

---

In general, **the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_0^t f(s)\mathrm{d}g(s)$ exists if $f$ is piecewise continuous and $g$ has finite variation.*** However, as you said, the sample paths of Brownian motion have infinite variation (yet finite quadratic variation). Your lemma states that every non-trivial continuous local martingale has infinite variation, as well. Thus, we have to use a new integral notion, Itô's integral. In fact, $\int_0^t B_s\mathrm{d}B_s=\frac{1}{2}(B_t^2-t)$ in the Itô sense.

*To prove this, we take a partition $0=t_0<t_1<...<t_n=t$ and choose $y_i^-$ such that
$$f(y^-_i) = \begin{cases} 
\inf\limits_{t_{i-1}\leq y\leq t_i}  f(y) &\mathrm{if}\; g(t_i)-g(t_{i-1})\geq0, \\
\sup\limits_{t_{i-1}\leq y\leq t_i}  f(y) &\mathrm{if}\; g(t_i)-g(t_{i-1})<0,
\end{cases} $$
and choose $y_i^+$ such that
$$f(y^+_i) = \begin{cases} 
\sup\limits_{t_{i-1}\leq y\leq t_i}  f(y) &\mathrm{if}\; g(t_i)-g(t_{i-1})\geq0, \\
\inf\limits_{t_{i-1}\leq y\leq t_i}  f(y) &\mathrm{if}\; g(t_i)-g(t_{i-1})<0,
\end{cases}.$$
Let
\begin{align*}
S^+_n(t) &= \sum_{i=1}^n f(y_i^+)(g(t_i)-g(t_{i-1})), \\
S^-_n(t) &= \sum_{i=1}^n f(y_i^-)(g(t_i)-g(t_{i-1})).
\end{align*}
Then, the Riemann-Stieltjes integral exists if $S^+_n(t)-S^-_n(t)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

However, if $\max\limits_{i=1,...,n} \{t_i-t_{i-1}\}\leq \delta$ for some $\delta>0$, then
\begin{align*}
S^+_n(t)-S^-_n(t) &\leq \sum_{i=1}^n |f(y_i^+)-f(y_i^-)||g(t_i)-g(t_{i-1})| \\
&\leq \sup\{|f(y)-f(y')| : y\geq0; y'\leq t,\;|y-y'|<\delta\} \sum_{i=1}^n |g(t_i)-g(t_{i-1})| \\
&\to 0,
\end{align*}
if $f$ is continuous (first term goes to zero) and $g$ has finite variation (the sum doesn't blow up). This, of course, also works if $f$ is piecewise continuous, we merely need to split up the integral domain.

**This is the reason why we need finite variation for $g$!** Otherwise, the Riemann-Stieltjes integral is simply not well-defined.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The lemma further states that every continuous adapted local martingale with finite variation and $M_{0} = 0$ is equal to zero right? Which means if we would use such an martingale as an integrator the integral would always be equal to zero or not?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. You know that the sample paths of such a process are almost surely constant and if $M_0=0$, then $M_t=0$ for all $t$ almost surely. These sample paths have, of course, finite variation and the Riemann–Stieltjes integral exists but if you ingrate any continous function with respect to a constant function, you obtain (as you said) zero.